# OpenGL rendering does not work correctly with OpenCV using GLSL shaders

Tags: opengl, opencv, glsl

I have coded a small OpenGL program using OpenGL and GLSL shaders. Here's a screen of my application :

[image]

Now, my objective is to mix my opengl frame and the one from my webcam in a unique frame using OpenCV. Before to do this with GLSL shaders, I tried to make a very simple program drawing a colored triangle with some basic OpenGL functions (glBengin, glVertex, etc.).

```
static int      initGL()
{
    if (!glfwInit())
        return (-1);

    if (!glfwOpenWindow(500, 500, 8, 8, 8, 0, 24, 0, GLFW_WINDOW)) {
        glfwTerminate();
        return (-1);
    }

    glEnable(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(45.0f, 500.0f / 500.0f, 0.1f, 100.0f);
    gluLookAt(0.0f, 0.0f, 5.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

    return (0);
}

static void     drawGL()
{
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glColor3ub(255, 0, 0);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glColor3ub(0, 255, 0);
    glVertex3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glColor3ub(0, 0, 255);
    glVertex3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glEnd();
}

int             main(void)
{
    initGL();

    CvCapture   *capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(CV_CAP_ANY);

    if (!capture) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: capture is NULL \n");
        getchar();
        return (-1);
    }

    while (1)
    {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glEnable(GL_MODELVIEW);

        IplImage    *frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);

        if (!frame) {
            fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: frame is null...\n");
            getchar();
            break;
        }

        glDrawPixels(frame->width, frame->height, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, frame->imageData);

        drawGL();

        glfwSwapBuffers();

        if ( (cvWaitKey(10) & 255) == 27 ) break;
    }

    cvReleaseCapture(&capture);
    cvDestroyWindow("mywindow");

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Here's the render :

[image]

As you can see the result is correct. Now, I wanted to try my first program using GLSL shaders with OpenCV like below but when my application is launched I have a black screen. I tried several tests and the problem seems to begin when I call glUseProgram function (so when I want to bind the program shader -> in my code it corresponds to the program->bind() call). But here I use the glDrawPixels function to load my video frame. I think it's not the good function to call if I want to use GLSL shaders. Here's a piece of my C++ code :

```
[...]

/*My GLSL shaders initialization*/

[...]
int                         main(int ac, char **av)
{
    bool                    isAlive = true;
    unsigned int            vaoID = 0;
    SDL_Event               event;
    GLuint                  textureID = 0;
    ShaderProgram           *program = NULL;

    if (!glfwInit())
        return (-1);

    if (!glfwOpenWindow(WIDTH, HEIGHT, 8, 8, 8, 0, 24, 0, GLFW_WINDOW)) {
        glfwTerminate();
        return (-1);
    }

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    //Viewport initialization

    glViewport(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    //Vertex declaration

    VertexDeclaration *vDeclar = initVertexDeclaration();

    //Glew init component

    glewInit();

    //VBO initialization

    VertexBuffer *vBuffer = initVBO();

    //Shaders initialization

    program = initShaders("triangle-pf.vert", "triangle-pf.frag");

    //Texture initialization

    textureID = loadBMPTexture("Box.bmp");

    //VAO initialization

    initVAO(vaoID, vBuffer, textureID, vDeclar);

    //Screen capture Initialization

    CvCapture   *capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(CV_CAP_ANY);

    if (!capture) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: capture is NULL \n");
        getchar();
        return (-1);
    }

    //Main loop

    while (isAlive == true)
    {
        //eventListener(&event, &isAlive);

        if (glfwGetKey(GLFW_KEY_ESC))
            isAlive = false;

        glClearDepth(1.0f);
        glClearColor(0.13f, 0.12f, 0.13f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        //---------------------------------------------------

        IplImage    *frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);

        if (!frame) {
            fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: frame is null...\n");
            getchar();
            break;
        }

        //---------------------------------------------------

        program->bind();

        //Projection matrix

        glm::mat4 ProjectionMatrix = glm::perspective(45.0f, 500.0f / 500.0f, 0.1f, 100.0f);

        //View matrix

        glm::mat4 ViewMatrix = glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 8.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));

        //Model matrix

        glm::mat4 ModelMatrix = glm::mat4(1.0f);
        ModelMatrix = glm::translate(ModelMatrix, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
        ModelMatrix = glm::rotate(ModelMatrix, angle, glm::vec3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f));
        ModelMatrix = glm::scale(ModelMatrix, glm::vec3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f));

        //Prepare matrix

        glm::mat4 ModelViewMatrix = ViewMatrix * ModelMatrix;
        glm::mat3 NormalMatrix = glm::mat3(glm::vec3(ModelViewMatrix[0]), glm::vec3(ModelViewMatrix[1]), glm::vec3(ModelViewMatrix[2]));
        glm::mat4 ModelViewProjectionMatrix = ProjectionMatrix * ModelViewMatrix;
        glm::vec4 LightPositionVec1 = ViewMatrix * glm::vec4(LightPosition1[0], LightPosition1[1], LightPosition1[2], LightPosition1[3]);

        //Send source light properties

        program->setUniform("LightInfos[0].La", glm::vec3(0.000000f, 0.000000f, 0.000000f));
        program->setUniform("LightInfos[0].Ld", glm::vec3(0.800000f, 0.800000f, 0.800000f));
        program->setUniform("LightInfos[0].Ls", glm::vec3(1.000000f, 1.000000f, 1.000000f));
        program->setUniform("LightInfos[0].Le", glm::vec3(0.200000f, 0.200000f, 0.200000f));

        /*program->setUniform("LightInfos[1].La", glm::vec3(0.000000f, 0.000000f, 0.000000f));
        program->setUniform("LightInfos[1].Ld", glm::vec3(0.800000f, 0.800000f, 0.800000f));
        program->setUniform("LightInfos[1].Ls", glm::vec3(0.000000f, 1.000000f, 1.000000f));
        program->setUniform("LightInfos[1].Le", glm::vec3(0.200000f, 0.200000f, 0.200000f));*/

        //Send model materials properties

        program->setUniform("MaterialInfos.Ka", glm::vec3(0.000000f, 0.000000f, 0.000000f));
        program->setUniform("MaterialInfos.Kd", glm::vec3(1.000000f, 1.000000f, 1.000000f));
        program->setUniform("MaterialInfos.Ks", glm::vec3(1.000000f, 1.000000f, 1.000000f));
        program->setUniform("MaterialInfos.Ke", glm::vec3(0.200000f, 0.000000f, 0.200000f));
        program->setUniform("MaterialInfos.Shininess", 10.0f);

        //Send light position

        program->setUniform("LightInfos[0].Position", LightPositionVec1);

        //Send matrix

        program->setUniform("ProjectionMatrix", ProjectionMatrix);
        program->setUniform("NormalMatrix", NormalMatrix);
        program->setUniform("ModelViewMatrix", ModelViewMatrix);
        program->setUniform("ModelMatrix", ModelMatrix);
        program->setUniform("MVP", ModelViewProjectionMatrix);

        glDrawPixels(frame->width, frame->height, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, frame->imageData);

        //VAO binding

        glBindVertexArray(vaoID);

        //Render meshes

        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vBuffer->getSize());

        glBindVertexArray(0);

        program->release();

        angle += 0.50f;

        glFlush();
        glfwSwapBuffers();
    }

    unsigned int vboID = vBuffer->getHandle();
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &vboID);
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &vaoID);
    return (0);
}
```

So I think the problem comes from glDrawPixels which cannot be used with GLSL shaders. I tried several possible ways without any success. Maybe I have to send the video frame buffer directly to the pixel shader ? In this case, how can I do that ? I'm really lost. Does anyone can help me?

Comment: "Mix my opengl frame and the one from my webcam in a unique frame using OpenCV," what does that mean? Can't you just render a quad in the background, and use the image data from OpenCV as a texture, then draw other 3D objects on top? I don't understand why you want to use a shader. What is the shader supposed to do?

Comment: I use shaders to compute some light effects which are not possible to render with a basic Opengl usage. I just want to render my cube and have my real time video as a background (like the example with the triangle above). It's like a juxtaposition of the video frame (from my webcam) and the other frame with the cube. Do you see what I mean ?

Comment: Yes, that's called augmented reality. Do you need these light effects applied to your background or the 3D objects?

Comment: My light effects are applied only on my 3D object like on my first picture. The background is just the video stream from the webcam. It's not a texture (picture number 2). The example with the triangle above works like that. I don't use any texture on the background, it's just the video stream. And I draw a simple triangle on it. I just want to have the same behaviour but using GLSL shaders.

Comment: You do know that you can use a shader for the 3D objects, but keep the old code for the background, right? I still don't understand why you would want to use a shader for the background, since you don't seem to need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you would set this up is to use your image data as a texture. [This link](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Texture) might be a good starting point. You can then render a quad in the background, which fills the entire screen, and uses the texture to determine the color of each pixel. The advantage over `glDrawPixels()` is that if you scale the window (and the quad), the image from the video will get scaled accordingly.

If you need to, you can use the texture in a shader when rendering that quad: The fragment (pixel) shader gets called for each pixel, and you would use a sampler to get the color from the texture. You can then modify that color according to your lighting needs.

What you draw on top of that is up to you.

Comment: Okay, that's a good answer. Thank you. I will try that. So about the little program I posted above with the colored triangle, it means that if I just get back the video stream in an OpenGL context (without the triangle), OpenGL create (in background) a texture (with the pixels buffer from the webcam for each video frame) and send it to its fragment shader and draws it to the screen. I know OpengL uses its own shaders (but the procedure is hidden). So I have to reproduce the same behaviour but this time with my own shaders. Is that right ?

Comment: I don't know how `glDrawPixels` is implemented. That might even depend on the hardware. But I still don't see the reason for using a shader for rendering the background if you don't need to modify how it's being rendered.

Comment: I just want to apply my shaders on my 3D model, not on the background because it's the video stream. The environment recorded by the webcam have to be the same. I only want to apply my luminosity effects on my 3D model. As you said it's augmented reality.

Comment: I think you might have the concept of shaders a little backwards. Think of a shader just as a texture, a way to assign colors to pixels. You can apply different shaders to different objects. You can apply multiple shaders to the same object. You could even have one shader for each triangle if you wanted to. And you can mix and match that with other tools like plain old texturing. In your code, you could call glDrawPixels first, then bind the shaders, and then only render the 3D model using the shaders.

Comment: Ok. I moved glDrawPixels call just above the shader program binding. I have a video stream but not the 3D model displayed. Do you know why ? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Not unless you post the shaders. :)

Comment: From what you said above, if I want to render the video stream in background and my 3D model together I'm obliged to create a texture with pixels from the video frame and put them on a quad. So in my scene I will have my cube plus the textured quad (which represents the video frame (webcam)). So my texture will change for each frame , for example if I move my webcam. Sorry, but I want to be sure about that.

Comment: Yes, that's how you could do it. You could also keep using glDrawPixels if that suits your needs. Remember that OpenGL is stateful. You can keep the rendering of the video completely separate from the rendering of the other objects if you change the state between rendering calls.